# How to remove unnecessary information inside comments for support tickets

Tags: 7, comments

I've installed Support module. And setup comments for it. Everything works fine, but comment contains a lot of unnecessary information:

[image]

I looked into comment section of Support ticket content type. But there is nothing I can do about it there:

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to hide some field values in the comments or all of them?

Comment: @ShawnConn I have already solved it by changing the module code.